# links do not have a hover effect

Tags: html, css

I noticed my a tags have no hover for some reason. I am thinking it has to do with my background video that I am using but not sure. Here is the jsfiddle and notice the red links have no hover.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9aen1w3/)

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="background-wrap">       
    <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
        <source src="north.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Video not supported
    </video>
</div>  
<div class="content">
    <h1>Video Background Tutorial</h1>
    <p>This tutorial shows you how to put video as a background for your website.</p>
</div>


*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    font-family:calibri,sans-serif;
}

.background-wrap{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#video-bg-elem{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
}

.content{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:1000;       
}

.content h1{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:65px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#fff;
    padding-top:15%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.content p{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    color:#aaa;
}

#navigation{
    float:right;
    margin-right:100px;
    margin-top:30px;
    width:400px;
}

#navigation ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
}

#navigation ul li a{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of **`z-index`**.

Either this 2 approach would fix that.

1.Just make your class **`.content`** to `z-index:-1` .

```
.content {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

2.Just make your class **`.content`** to `z-index:1` and add `position:relative` with `z-index:2`to id **`#navigation`** .

```
.content {
  z-index: 1;
}
#navigation {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

To learn more about **`z-index`**, check it [HERE](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

Answer (score 0):

Jef's code works, just add this too:

```
 #navigation ul li a:hover{
        color:red !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the "#navigation" css:

```
position: relative;
```

and add that:

```
z-index: 1001;
```

In your code:

```
#navigation {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this i have edited your code, just need to add some breaks after menu , else u achieve this with saying margin to  the video tag

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 
 body{
  font-family:calibri,sans-serif;
 }
 
 .background-wrap{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:-1000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:0;
  left:0;
 }
 
 #video-bg-elem{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
 }
 
 .content{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  z-index:1000;
  
 }
 
 .content h1{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:65px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:300;
  color:red;
  padding-top:15%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 }
 
 .content p{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  letter-spacing:3px;
  color:red;
 }
 
 #navigation{
  float:right;
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-top:30px;
 }
 
 #navigation ul li{
  float:left;
  margin-right:30px;
 }
 
 #navigation ul li a{
  color:red;
 }
  
  #navigation ul li a:hover{
  color:green !important;
 }
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="background-wrap">
  <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
  <source src="north.mp4" type="video/mp4">Video not supported </video>
</div>
 <div class="content">
  <h1>Video Background Tutorial</h1>
  <p>This tutorial shows you how to put video as a background for your website.</p>
 </div>
```